# Changing ComputerName and LocalHostName on Mac OS 10.14.4

Tags: macos, mac, hostname

I am not able to change my ComputerName nor my LocalHostName on my Macbook Air running Mac OS 10.14.4

What I have tried so far:

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "new-computer-name"
```

when trying to execute the above I receive the following output:

```
SCPreferencesCommitChanges() failed: Operation not permitted
```

From my understanding the function SCPreferencesCommitChanges() plays a role in changing the information that is stored in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

I am aware of Apple's SIP (System Integrity Protection) an how it prevents even root-users from manipulating certain files. However when executing

```
csrutil status
```

it told me that SIP wasn't even active in the first place. Still I restarted my Macbook in Recovery mode in order to disable it (yes, I know it seems redundant). 
After rebooting again, I tried

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "new-computer-name"
```

once again receiving the same output as before.

/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist permissions looks like this: -rw-r--r--

As expected the following did not help me either

```
sudo chmod 744 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

I would be thankful if anyone had any recommendations on how to solve this issue.

**edit: changed typo: scputil --> scutil**

Comment: [This procedure](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) might help.

Comment: @harrymc
Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.
I noticed that /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist is the only locked file in that directory. 
When I try to manipulate it a new file named 'preferences.plist-new' is created in the same directory. It contains the ComputerName / LocalHostName that I tried to set with scutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct procedure to do it for Mojave is:

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName ExampleName

sudo scutil --set LocalHostName ExampleName
```

You have to execute **both commands**, otherwise it may not completelly change the name.

PS: the command used here is **`scutil`**, not `scputil`

---

You also mentioned about having problems with that file access.
I verified on a newly installed MacOS the correct security flags for that file, and I suggest you adjust it to defaults before the procedure to change the name, please use the commands below:

`sudo chflags nouchg,noschg /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

`sudo chown root:wheel /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

`sudo chmod 644 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

The 3 commands above respectively Adjust the security flags of that file to default, adjust the user/group permissions to default, adjust the file access to defaults.